# Backend solution for fetching and transforming data from various third-party APIs

Tags: api, database-design, architecture, aggregation-framework, middleware

We are building new feature sets for one of our financial application. We have our own SQL server database and we will be calling multiple RESTful APIs that return JSON responses. For e.g. some returns news data, some returns stocks info, some returns finance data and our own sql server database has employee data. So, they all come with their own different data format. This new app we are building is going to aggregate all those data, transform it into meaningful display on web like mint.com does.

- Web application will display analytical reports based on these data
- There will be an option to download reports through various templates

We are completely open in terms of technology stack for our backend and middle-tier. As a first thought NoSQL like mongodb and elasticsearch for search and reporting comes to our mind. There will be a web application build on top of these data (stored or retrieved from API), most likely in Asp.net MVC.

We need your input, specially if you have experience with building similar enterprise solution.

Can you please share your opinions on,

1. What are some good tech stack you would pick for this app?
2. How would that scale now and in future when APIs data format changes.
3. Performance is also important since data will be displayed on web UI.

Comment: Off topic (opinion based & asking for recommendation for tools / libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a similar setup to what you are mentioning, using ASP.Net MVC with ElasticSearch (SQL server for relational data, periodically updating ES), aggregating data (XML/JSON) from multiple sources, although with the purpose of improving searching and filtering results instead of reporting. However, I would expect that the scenario you are looking at would also be a suitable match for ElasticSearch, depending on your specific requirements.

1) Since you are already using SQL Server (and I expect are familiar with that), I would suggest combining that with ElasticSearch - the additional mongodb layer seems unnecessary, in terms of maintenance of another technology and development to fit that integration. There is a very good C# library (two actually, [ElasticSearch.Net](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_elasticsearch_net.html) and [NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/), used together) that exposes most of the ES functionality.

2) We chose ElasticSearch for its scalability in combination with flexibility and ease-of-use. A challenge you may face could be mapping the documents from C# classes to ElasticSearch documents. In essence, it is incredibly easy to set up, however you do need to do some planning to index data *the way you want to search and retrieve it*. So if choosing ES as a platform, spend some time with the structure of the documents - by default, `dynamic mapping` is enabled, so you can pretty much throw any JSON into a document. However, for a production environment, it's better to turn that off and have one or more mappings set up, so they can be queried in a standardized way.

3) Performance is a key factor for us as well, which is why we were looking at Lucene-based engines like Solr and ElasticSearch when doing research, along with NoSQL databases. ElasticSearch outperforms SQL Server by *10 to 1 or better*, in most scenarios. Solr vs. ElasticSearch performance depends on scenario, benchmarks and [comparisons](http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com/) are around if you Google them. The exception may be if many documents should be retrieved in one query - ES (or Lucene) is not made for that use case, it's best for fast retrieval of fewer results (similar to Google's per page results count) per page. If you need 1000 documents per page/result, a NoSQL database may be a better option.

ElasticSearch is fast to get up and running - install it on a local development box and try it out, you'll get a feel for if it fits.

Comment: Calie, yes, i think sql server may be able to handle everything but search. Just curious, when you fetch data from multiple sources, do you store any part of those data - temporary or permanent? how do you deal with changing format of those xml/json responses from third-party source? sql server schema will have to be altered to meet new format.

Comment: @Priyank, we use C# to convert XML/JSON to our data structure in SQL Server. A possibility would be to use XSLT transformation, but I don't have good experience with that. Instead, we have identified common denominators and build our data structure based on that, then we convert each set of documents to that, using C# logic. Some are straight copying of values, some require a lot of business logic to convert.

Comment: Thanks Calie, my question was for actual sql server database table schema, today i design a table with 10 columns and tomorrow, api changed fields in their xml/json response and removed/added some data, you have to alter the table design to fit that new response right. this was the normal process i know and was wondering if there is any better solution to this.

Comment: @Priyank, I think that's part of the planning process, to look at the structure of *all* of the known formats available, then create a data structure that can handle those, and also potential changes that may come. However, they'll never be perfect, you can expect schema changes underway. Fortunately, the schema changes are few and far between, so solving this with a certain degree of normalization does the trick, I think.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, mongodb is the worst choice for reporting, especially for aggregation. It lacks in good aggregation functionality, has some data type conflicts (such as decimals being stored as strings, which you cannot use in it's built in aggregation framework api) and you'll probably will have to maintain map-reduce functions in javascript for most of the scenarios.

If your application's true nature is only reports, and they do not have to be updated in realtime, I would drop off the on-demand RPC calls to external APIs. I would consider copying ahead as much data as possible and storing it under a schema that is the most convenient for you to work with, and synchronising it afterwards under scheduled, predicted intervals.

I wouldn't be in a hurry making assumptions about that data to be available all the time nor it always to be in the format you expect. You also gain optimisation benefits on running your own copy of it, indexed in the way you want, instead of trying to figure which of the RPCs is your bottleneck.

As for your questions:

1) If you don't mind using Python, I would pick Django on top of PostgresSQL database. Django is a fully featured sturdy ORM + Web framework which is excellent for this kind of work. If not, just stick to a relational SQL database. I heard wonders of Cassandra but haven't tried it yet.

2 + 3) As I mentioned before, replicating the data as much as possible for your own good. After everything is "in house" you can cluster it and tweak it freely. Using a distributed cache against heavy client requests is also a good idea (such as REDIS), instead of generating those reports each time on demand.

Comment: i liked all the points you made. i looked into postgresSQL and learned it also supports JSON type column. for now, thinking about sticking to sql server since we already invested in it. also i am concerned about storing copy of API responses locally, have to check terms & conditions of provider since some of them don't allow caching data and some do for limited period.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Jasper reports and the Jasper Reports Server to integrate into our web app. Jasper accepts many different datasource types including JSON and SQLServer. The core version is free and allows you to product html amd pdf reports of high complexity. The paid version with the server allows you to easily integrate in your web app. The core is Java spring (partially open source) running on tomcat/jboss and you can interact with it using REST web services or the visualize.js library for your web front end. It uses highcharts which can produce some beautiful results and has options for adhoc reporting and dashboards built from many reports.

See demos here: http://www.jaspersoft.com/

This has an assumed stack of your backend db's and data sources, tomcat with Java Spring, web front end HTML/Javascript.

The tool is used by many large enterprises including Amazon so scalibility so shouldn't be an issue.

If the format of your data changes you'll need to change the report. This is xml formatted editted by GUI with WYSIWYG.